# Call signal only for the current object

Tags: python, django, model, signals

I'm working with django 1.6 with signals.
I have model `Events` with field `is_cyclic` and I want to run signal only for one, current object. But it seems that my code goes through all objects and I get an error:

```
maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Here is my signal

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Events)
def my_callback(sender, created, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    db_name = args[0] if len(args) else 'events'
    print('using %s' % db_name)
    list = loader.get_template('events/event_list_item.html')
    list_small = loader.get_template('events/event_list_item_small.html')
    setattr(instance, 'is_cyclic', list.render(Context({'e': instance})))
    setattr(instance, 'is_cyclic', list_small.render(Context({'e': instance})))
    instance.save(using=db_name)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read your code ? You have a function that calls `Event.save()`, and you bind it to the `models.post_save()` signal for the `Event` model.

`models.post_save()` signal is sent after a model instance is saved. So when your callback calls `instance.save()`, it triggers the `post_save` signal, which calls your callback function, which saves the instance, which triggers the `post_save` signal, which calls your callback function, which saves the instance, which triggers the `post_save` signal, which calls your callback function, etc etc etc.

You are actually lucky that Python limits the recursion to a given depth, else this would recurse forever.

as a side note:

- you don' need `setattr()` here, you could just use the obvious `instance.is_cyclic = <whatever>` attribute assignment syntax
- you are setting the same attribute to two different values so the first one is replaced by the second, IOW the first `setattr` call is a pure waste of time
- I really don't understand why you want to assign the result of a template rendering to an instance attribute (if you want caching, Django has a full featured cache framework already)
- and I totally fail to understand why you would assign this to an attribute which names implies some boolean flag

Comment: Nice :) Thank you for open my eyes :)